# ¿Como funciona el "if"?

Tags: if, programación-bajo-nivel

Tengo esa duda de como funciona el `if` en programación de bajo nivel.

Si es que hace la comprobación en la **RAM** pasando por todas la direcciones que la contienen.

Comment: Recuerdo hace tiempo, esto fue una pregunta de tarea bastante interesante... es tarea?

Comment: No, una duda que tengo hace mucho tiempo.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Buenas.

Los if de alto nivel no son iguales que los de bajo nivel. Un if no se compara en la ram, el procesador carga los datos de la memoria Ram a los registros (EAX, EDX, etc. Estos son como "variables" que el procesador tiene físicamente por medio de transitores y elementos electrónicos) Luego compara estos registros con la instrucción [CMP y las instrucciones de control de flujo](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow) como JNZ, JG, JL, JO. Estas instrucciones son nombres simbólicos de valores binarios, esto es para que el programador pueda entender el programa, pero un entorno de desarrollo de ensamblador suele tener este aspecto:

[image: asm]

Donde se ven una estructura como:

[*dirección de memoria*] [*codigo de instruccion*] [*codigo mnemónico*][*; y algunas veces comentarios*]

Entonces la instrucción CMP compara dos registros y activa las [banderas [FLAGS]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) correspondientes. Luego una instrucción de salto como JE (salto si es igual) determina donde continua el flujo del programa según la bandera que le corresponde moviendo el puntero EIP (Instruction pointer register). Luego de esto se ejecutan los bloques de instrucciones correspondientes.

Puedes ver el ejemplo de código de alto nivel vs uno de bajo nivel completo en [esta pregunta que respondí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10234/ayuda-con-problema-en-lenguaje-ensamblador) hace tiempo. Este es una parte del código, ambos hacen lo mismo:

Asm

```
mov     CX, offset texto1       ; Carga de variables en registros
mov     BX, offset texto1
mov     DX, offset texto1       
add     DX, largoTexto         

ip_for:                         
cmp     CX, DX                  ; Comparacion de registros CX y DX esto activa todas las banderas que correspondan
jge     ip_forend               ; Si CX es mayor o igual que DX sale del ciclo o sea salta a la direccion de ip_forend
inc     CX                      ; Si no se cumple la condicion de salto, la rutina sigue en la siguiente instruccion

ip_if1:                        
mov     DI, CX                 
mov     AL, byte ptr[DI]       
cmp     AL, 32                 
jne     ip_if2                  ; otro ejemplo de If aqui!
cmp     CX, offset texto1      
je      ip_if2                  ; y aqui
mov     SI, BX                 
mov     DI, CX                 
dec     DI                     
mov     BX, CX                 
inc     BX                     
jmp     ip_while               ; este es un salto incondicional, siempre salta

ip_if2:                         
mov     AX, DX                  
dec     AX                      
cmp     CX, AX                  
jne     ip_for                 ; otra comparacion aqui
mov     SI, BX                  
mov     DI, CX                  

ip_while:                      
cmp     SI, DI 
jge     ip_for
mov     AL, byte ptr[SI]
xchg    AL, byte ptr[DI]
xchg    AL, byte ptr[SI]
inc     SI
dec     DI
jmp     ip_while

ip_forend:
```

Java

```
for (int CX = 0, BX = 0, DX = largoTexto; CX < DX; CX++) {
    if (texto1[CX] == ' ' && CX != 0) {
        SI = BX;
        DI = CX;
        DI--;
        BX = CX;
        BX++;
    } else if (CX == DX - 1) {
        SI = BX;
        DI = CX;
    } else {
        continue;
    }

    while (SI < DI) {
        char AL = texto1[SI];
        texto1[SI] = texto1[DI];
        texto1[DI] = AL;
        SI++;
        DI--;
    }
}
```

Comment: En su ejemplo asm porque no limpia la parte alta del registro `ah` En `ip_f1`. Se considera una buena práctica creo??

Comment: Sinceramente no se si es una buena práctica. Pero según mi lógica, si no uso esa parte del registro como sumador, no es necesario limpiarla, solo sería una instrucción de mas :P, de todas formas, cualquier cosa que mejore la respuesta, se puede agregar como edición (siempre que no rompa el ejemplo :P)

Comment: Es una buena práctica en mi opinión. Siempre es bueno limpiar la basura de la memoria.  Quizá no sea tan relevante para el ejemplo del if pero por ejemplo si se trabaja con servicios es importante.  Igual es una buena explicación.